# How do I select a value in an array/list, using its number in order?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fill a grid with values that can be entered by the user. I was going to use an array to store the values but I can't figure out how to select a value using which number it is down the array (For example, if an array was [A, B, C, D] and I wanted to select C, I would use 3).

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<title>Events</title>
<style>
.win { color: #FFD700; font-family: Consolas }
h1 {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
body {
    font-family: Bahnschrift;
    background-color: rgb(15, 150, 38);
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    background-color: rgb(15, 150, 38);
    padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
    background-color: rgb(15, 150, 38);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 33px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script>
const Games = [
"0","0","0","0","0", <!-- Team 1 --> 
"0","0","0","0","0", <!-- Team 2 -->
"0","0","0","0","0", <!-- Team 3 -->
"0","0","0","0","0", <!-- Team 4 -->
"0","0","0","0","0", <!-- Team 5 -->
"0","0","0","0","0"] <!-- Team 6 -->
</script>
<body>

</body>
<h1>
<div style="float:left;"><a href="https://unit-4-bandc.tiiny.site"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/VwCkgck/Left-arrow.png" alt="Left-arrow"></a></div>
<div style="float:right;"><a href="https://unit-4-bandc.tiiny.site/Teams.html"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/mhS1k4k/Right-arrow.png" alt="Right-arrow"></a></div>
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100px;">Events</div></h1>
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item">Game 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Game 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Game 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Game 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Game 5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Team 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 1, Game 1-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 1, Game 2-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 1, Game 3-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 1, Game 4-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 1, Game 5-->
    <div class="grid-item">Team 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 2, Game 1-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 2, Game 2-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 2, Game 3-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 2, Game 4-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 2, Game 5-->
    <div class="grid-item">Team 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 3, Game 1-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 3, Game 2-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 3, Game 3-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 3, Game 4-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 3, Game 5-->
    <div class="grid-item">Team 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 4, Game 1-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 4, Game 2-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 4, Game 3-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 4, Game 4-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 4, Game 5-->
    <div class="grid-item">Team 5</div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 5, Game 1-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 5, Game 2-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 5, Game 3-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 5, Game 4-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 5, Game 5-->
    <div class="grid-item">Team 6</div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 6, Game 1-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 6, Game 2-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 6, Game 3-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 6, Game 4-->
    <div class="grid-item"></div> <!--Team 6, Game 5-->
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

Bracket notation allows you to read and write data in a specific position. Keep in mind that arrays are zero indexed, meaning the first element of the array has an index of 0.

```js
let yourArray = ["A", "B", "C"];

// Accessing an element in the array
const firstElement = yourArray[0]; // "A"

// Adding an element to the array or changing an existing one
yourArray[0] = "D"; // ["D", "B", "C"]
```

You can find more [examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#access_an_array_item_by_its_index).

Answer (score 0):

You can also nest arrays in the arrays like this:

```
const games = [
  [0,0,0,0],
  [5,6,7,8],
  [2,2,2,2]
]
```

and use it like this:

```
const teamAlfa = games[0]
const teamBravo = games[1]
```

and so on, and then f.e.
`teamBravo[0]` will be equal to 5

from this point you can do all sort of useful stuff with array functions like `.reduce()`, `.forEach()` etc.